# Elasticsearch - How to change the sort type of phrase suggester's direct generator?

Tags: elasticsearch, search-engine, search-suggestion

I am trying create did-you-mean feature with using phrase suggester. When i give my text to term suggester and sort results by score, I am getting most wanted results at the top of the term based suggestions. But combining these separate results seems pointless to me since we have phrase suggesters. However, when i try a phrase suggester with the same parameters as my previous term suggester, i am not getting the wanted result.

```
"my-title-suggestions-3": [
     {
        "text": "devloping",
        "offset": 0,
        "length": 9,
        "options": [
           {
              "text": "developing",
              "score": 0.8888889,
              "freq": 340
           },
           {
              "text": "deploying",
              "score": 0.7777778,
              "freq": 24
           },
           {
              "text": "devoting",
              "score": 0.75,
              "freq": 3
           }
        ]
     },
     {
        "text": "distibutd",
        "offset": 10,
        "length": 9,
        "options": [
           {
              "text": "distributed",
              "score": 0.7777778,
              "freq": 32
           },
           {
              "text": "distribute",
              "score": 0.7777778,
              "freq": 31
           }
        ]
     },
     {
        "text": "saerch",
        "offset": 20,
        "length": 6,
        "options": [
           {
              "text": "search",
              "score": 0.8333333,
              "freq": 367
           },
           {
              "text": "speech",
              "score": 0.6666666,
              "freq": 54
           },
           {
              "text": "sketch",
              "score": 0.6666666,
              "freq": 11
           }
        ]
     },
     {
        "text": "engies",
        "offset": 27,
        "length": 6,
        "options": [
           {
              "text": "engines",
              "score": 0.8333333,
              "freq": 80
           },
           {
              "text": "engine",
              "score": 0.6666666,
              "freq": 217
           },
           {
              "text": "entries",
              "score": 0.6666666,
              "freq": 15
           }
        ]
     }
  ]
```

Above shows term frequencies and score getting from term suggester.

And below is what i get with phrase one:

```
   "suggest": {
  "simple_phrase": [
     {
        "text": "devloping distibutd saerch engies",
        "offset": 0,
        "length": 33,
        "options": [
           {
              "text": "developing distributed search engine",
              "highlighted": "<em>developing distributed search engine</em>",
              "score": 8.401011e-8
           },
           {
              "text": "developing distribute search engine",
              "highlighted": "<em>developing distribute search engine</em>",
              "score": 6.85284e-8
           },
           {
              "text": "developing distributed search engines",
              "highlighted": "<em>developing distributed search engines</em>",
              "score": 5.546362e-8
           },
           {
              "text": "developing distribute search engines",
              "highlighted": "<em>developing distribute search engines</em>",
              "score": 5.2338663e-8
           },
           {
              "text": "developing distributed speech engine",
              "highlighted": "<em>developing distributed speech engine</em>",
              "score": 3.586202e-8
           }
        ]
     }
  ]
```

It seems that phrase suggester uses term frequencies to combine what comes from direct suggesters. However as you can see above it is not the wanted result and the real good suggestion falls into third place in this situation. Is there a way to change this behaviour and combine term based suggestions with respect to their scores in phrase suggester?